# crytal report runtime issue on 64bit

Tags: .net, oracle, deployment, crystal-reports

In my Company we had a ERP developed on Vb.net (framewrk2.0) with back end oracle 8i and for reporting part crystal report 9. My company was reluctant for changes and they never upgraded any of these

Now its my  turn to support these application .The issue iam facing is I cannot install oracle client  in 64 bit systems. I solved it by installing oracle 10g client and connecting to database instance

And since the crystal report runtime for .net2  32 bit doesnt work I had installed 64 bit but nnow the issue is when I  try to intiate any report It ask for login even if we give credentials it says logon fails 
Is there any  tip in solving this logon issue in crystal report

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your report Connection. or If u have used .dsn so please check Dsn Connection.

Comment: can you please explain a little more on  your answer as iam not able to find anything via googling

Comment: means check your report connection.